# private instance variable accessible with "public" scope inside compareTo

Tags: java, private, public, compareto

Strangely, instance variable `brand` is private scope, yet accessible the "public" way inside of method `compareTo`.

```
public class Car implements Comparable<Car> {
    private String brand;

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public int compareTo(Car o) {
        return this.brand.compareTo(o.brand);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's a true statement.  What is the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class variable `brand` is private to other classes not the class `Car` itself.

for instance if you try

```
class Foo
{
     Foo()
     {
          Car car = new Car();
          string brand = car.brand; // <-- will not compile; 
                                    // should use car.getBrand()
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the brand member of the instance O because you are in another instance of the same type

Answer (score 1):

`Private` specifies that the variable can only be accessed by members of the class. There is nothing wrong with the scenario above.